# Attach Cloud Storage as External Drive to Windows

Tags: windows, storage, cloud-storage, scsi, iscsi

I am looking to use a Cloud Storage provider as an attached drive on Windows Server 2008, kind of like an iSCSI storage device.

I downloaded Google Drive which created a new folder on my system, but it downloaded the files on Google Drive to my local system. The reason for doing this is to save space on my system, but Google Drive just duplicates everything in the cloud locally eating up space.

Is there a way to connect it as a separate drive so it doesn't effect local disk space, or is there any other service that does this. An in the cloud iSCSI provider if you like. I know about Dropbox etc... but my understanding is they act the same as Google Drive, keeping local copies of everything.

Comment: It is very unlikely, that such a service could function: Typical **real achievable** bandwidth to a drive in your computer is 3Gbit/s or more with latencies in the low microseconds (or even high nanoseconds). Anything over the internet will be connected orders of magnitude worse.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=iscsi+cloud

Comment: Thanks @agtoever I had already done that, I probably could have worded my question better. I am looking to use a service like Google Drive or Dropbox, or for a new service like Google Drive or Dropbox (i.e. A Freemium service). AWS etc... is very expensive

Comment: It may be worth your while to keep an eye on [win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/).  It doesn't officially support Windows 2008 at the moment, but is based on the *nix utility `sshfs` which allows you to mount a remote filesystem that you have access to via normal SSH (mount, not copy).  It functionally works similarly to NFS or Samba, but is a bit more secure when used over the public Internet.  You would of course still need to have a remote server to use for storage.

Comment: You can use Google Drive as a share just not by installing the Google Drive application.  You can do the same with OneDrive and Dropbox I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

I use a service called storagemadeeasy.com. Their service connects to multiple cloud providers. It's reasonably priced with a lifetime cloud option that makes it a one time service fee. Then, they have an add-on to allow FTP connections, which should do what you're wanting. You will still need a third-party software like Netdrive to map an FTP to a drive  letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a software called WebDrive. Early, they used to mount a drive letter to a FTP site, but later on came to support cloud services like DropBox. These services won't work on the block level like iSCSI, but you also don't have to keep a local snapshot of all your cloud files.